# "It won't take but a moment"

Tags: adverbs

> I open the door.
>
> "Marlena!" I say,
>   swinging the door farther open than I intend to. "What are you doing
>   up? I mean, are you okay? Do you want to sit down?"
>
> "No," she says. Her face is inches from mine. "I'm all
>   right. But I'd like to speak to you for a moment. Are you alone?"
>
> "Uh, no. Not exactly." I say, glancing back at
>   Walter, who's shaking his head and waving his hands furiously.
>
> "Can you come to the stateroom?" Marlena says. "It won't
>   take ***but*** a moment."
>
> “Yes. Of course.”
>
> -- *Sara Gruen, Water for Elephants*

What does ***but*** mean? (The sentence seems like *it won’t take time except that it takes only a moment*, I suppose.)

Comment: "but" in this content means "only". Only a moment. So the sentence means the same as "It won't take a moment". (That is, it will take even less than one moment.)

Comment: @MrLister I agree with the first part of your comment.  It does not, however, mean "it will take even less than one moment".  (Not that there's a big difference between one moment and less than one moment, mind you...)

Comment: Hm, then what is the difference between "it _will_ take but a moment" (from your answer) and "it _won't_ take but a moment" (from the question)?

Comment: A negative with *but* is like a positive with *only*.  It's an **exceptive construction**; like when you say "No one but Joe ate cake", you mean "Only Joe ate cake".  Here, "not but a moment" means "only a moment".  I apologize for my answer being unclear!

Comment: @MrLister Ah, I see your question. I think they mean the same thing.  *Not ... but* means "only", and *but* can mean "only", as well!

Comment: @Mr Lister, snailboat: I think the presence or absence of ***but*** is irrelevant to the fact that for many speakers in many contexts the negation itself also makes no inherent difference to the "duration" meaning. The biggest difference between *"It won't take a minute"* and *"It will take a minute"* is nothing to do with whether it takes exactly one minute, or more, or less. It's that (unless it includes the word "only") the non-negated version implies that a minute is *a relatively long time*, in the context of whatever "it" is that might be done.

Comment: @snailboat I don't think you can classify this as an exceptive; it is paralleled by "It won't take only a moment". Both the *but* and *only* versions are colloquial double negatives, and are, I surmise, not conscious emphatics but casual use of unanalyzed fixed phrases--compare "I couldn't care less".  None of these would be accepted in a formal register.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, there's definitely something of the "optional double negative" in such constructions. Semantically it makes no real difference whether either or both elements (negated verb *and/or* a qualifier such as ***but, only, just***) are included. It's just that including *neither* implies the speaker thinks the amount of time is at least *long enough* to bother mentioning, and including *both* is informal/dialectal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nicely discriminated.

Comment: [*Billy is prejudiced cause Jacks father is **nothing only but just** a humble butcher*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22father+is+nothing+only+but+just+a+humble+butcher%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is perhaps a rather extreme example, but it'd mean exactly the same (and still be in the same "register") if it'd been ***ain't*** instead of ***is***. In such constructions, so long as you have at least *one* negating/minimising qualifier, it makes little difference semantically (except perhaps by adding *emphasis*) if you add more such terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sense 10 in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but):

> just; merely; only ⇒ "he was but a child", "I can but try"

Here, the sentence means "it will only take a moment".  In other words, it won't take more than one moment.

Comment: "Merely", yes, that was the word I was looking for.